# How to make open programs in Unity launcher appear at the top of the list

Tags: unity, launcher

I have lots of program launchers in Unity, using the whole height of the screen on the left side (as by default). If I open a program, which is NOT in the launcher, its icon will be located at the bottom side of the launcher list, next to the rubbish bin.
So, some programs with open windows (that I'm actually using) will be a bit hidden downside.
But I would like to have the running applications on the top, for better reach. That is because sometimes I work on ten documents at the same time, for which it is not very comfortable to use the switcher (what I do, so this not the solution).

Is there a way to customize the location where starting programs appear in the launcher?

I DON'T mean to just drag and drop that icons to a new location, as I want them to appear only during the time that I am using that program (if I drag them to a new location, they will stay there afterwards).

---

Still no answer to this question, but as I think it would be a very important feature for the Unity launcher, to have all the open programs on the top of the launcher (next to the dash), I will add some information.

There is a new unity-teak-tool in the repositories. I installed and studied it, but couldn't find a way to specify, where open programs should appear in the launcher list.

Comment: I think it is currently not possible, Unity itself would need to be modified for this.

Comment: Could you tell me, where I can propose new features for the next Ubuntu?

Comment: You may create a Blueprint at [Unity's Launchpad page](https://launchpad.net/unity)